# Order items in a ItemsControl from right top to left bottom

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to set a list in an ItemsControl in one of the views of my WPF application.

The problem is I want an other order of my items which are displayed in the control.
Prmiary, the ItemsControl displays items left to right and top to bottom :

```
1  2  3  4   5   6
7  8  9  10  11  12
```

However, I want to display my items in a other way - from right top to left bottom - like this :

```
11  9   7  5  3  1
12  10  8  6  4  2
```

My current ItemsControl is :

```
        Grid.Column="1"
        BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource WindowTitleColorBrush}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Truck.Containers}">
         <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <UniformGrid Rows="2" />
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Border>
```

I cannot just reorder my list by descending in the viewmodel as it will start with 12 and finish with 1 and not 11 - 2.
Is there an other way to display my list in the order I want ?

Comment: Best way would be to order the items in the way you want in the ViewModel.

Comment: half of the solution is in `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"` on the UniformGrid. The other half you can solve by making derived class as described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/104b9cb8-3e1a-4e2e-ac62-4f9b32cc21f0/layout-orientation-of-uniformgrid?forum=wpf)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow one of 3 solutions:

1. Order your items as you want in View Model
2. Use `CollectionViewSource` - do your custom ordering there
3. Create a custom `Panel` that orders items as you want, and use it as `ItemsPanelTemplate`. To create a custom panel, create a custom class and inherit from `Panel` or `UniformGrid`. Than override two methods:

> MeasureOverride - to determine the required size of the panel
> according to the desired size of the child elements and the available
> space.
>
> ArrangeOverride - to arrange the elements in the finally
> available space. The final size can be smaller than the requested.

More about custom panels in this [msdn link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-panel-element) and this [tutorial](https://www.wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html).

You can also take a look at [UniformGrid source code on msdn](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/UniformGrid.cs,a4592db73e6521dc).

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion to do it in code : split your list even or odd, order this two list by descending then add the elements from the two previous list in a third list bound to your ItemsControl !